# Hires, interlaced screen on Amiga HiSoft C, with window, menu and buttons

Tags: c, motorola, amiga

I'm an Amiga programming newbie.

I need to produce an application that displays graphics in a similar way to the popular drawing application, Deluxe Paint by Dan Silva, published by Electronic Arts. Just a vertically scrolling image, preferably in HAM mode.

**How do I open a new screen based on the result from a screenmode requester dialogue box using HiSoft C for the Amiga?**

Requirements:

- Open a new hires interlaced screen in as many colours as hardware will allow
- Basic menu structure that I can manipulate (Top Right-click menu)
- A project window, similar to the HiSoft C editor
- A control panel along the top similar to the one in Digita Wordworth with text boxes, buttons and tabs
- I also need an off screen buffer that is as wide as the screen and as tall as memory will allow.

This needs to be compatible with:

- Workbench 3.0 and above
- 68020 and above
- ECS & AGA chipset
- 0.5..2Mb chipmem + 0..∞ fastmem

Comment: The first thing to do is to find a copy of the Native Developer Kit (can apparently be found [here](http://www.vesalia.de/e_developer2.htm)). Any version up to and including version 3.9 can be used. It should contain plenty of examples, as well as a very detailed reference of, well, everything.

Comment: As for C compiler you could use DICE, whose source can be downloaded [from here](http://www.obviously.com/dice/) and cross-compiled on basically any UNIX-like machine.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I bought the CD and Haage&Partner's StormC compiler comes bundled on it. For this project I need to use HiSoft C by order of the proposal, but the CD has some interesting stuff on it too.

Comment: In an attempt to clear the fog for Luv, syb0rg, Kevin, 1 and Sauabh. Like many questions on here, not everyone will understand the question being asked. luckykaa understood the question and came up with a possible solution. There is a model of computer called the Amiga and a version of the C language by a company called HiSoft. What Ineed help with is to create a skeleton project for standard windows style applications, but instead of using Windows, I want the program to run under the Workbench operating system.

Answer (score 3):

From the question, I'm not sure how experienced you are with Amiga programming. If you have zero experience with the way windows and screens are set up, then I can strongly recommend [Anders Bjerin's Amiga C Manual](http://aminet.net/package/dev/c/ACM_PDF)

It's fairly old and predates AGA, but it shouldn't be a huge problem to extrapolate how to open a 256 colour screen.

Comment: Thank you for the tip luckykaa. The link is broken, which you might want to fix, but it got me to aminet at least, and from there I searched and found it. Thank you so much